# how to downgrade the kotlin version

Tags: kotlin, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I use map_view library  in flutter project 
the error was 
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher. Project 'map_view' is using version 1.2.50.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.
Go to YourFlutterProject/android/build.gradle

Replace to.

```
buildscript{
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
....
```

Comment: Run "flutter clean" and try again. And if still has an issue, please share your pubspec.yaml file content.

Comment: try it doesn't work the pubsoec.yaml     version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  scoped_model: ^1.0.1  
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  rxdart: ^0.22.3
  map_view:  ^0.0.14
  location:  ^2.3.5
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

Comment: and the build.gradle filebuildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10' ////1.2.71
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}